# How to increment by 3 in PHP

Tags: php

```
    $arr = array('cat','dog','spider','snake');
                $arrlength = count($arr);

               $a = 1; 
               $i = 0;

                while($a <= 3) :?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php for($x=$i; $x < $arrlength;$x++):?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="" <?php echo $name?>><?php echo $arr[$x]?><br/>
                            </label>
                        </div>                    
                    <?php endfor; ?>  
                </div>
                <?php $a++; endwhile;?>
```

How do I increment the value of $i by 3 every increment of $a?

Thanks for your responce.

Comment: `<?php $a++; $i+=3; endwhile;?>`?

Comment: Let's assume that we have 9 records in our array. what I want is on the first execution I just want to display the 0,1,2 index of the array then when the $a is incremented then display 3,4,5 then for the last execution I want to display the 6,7,8 of the array index. Is that possible?

Comment: start from `$a = 0`, `$i = 0`. for every element you increment `$i++`. then for every 3 elements you increment `$a++` and reset `$i = 0`. 
you can access the array by `$array[$a*3+$i]`

Comment: Thank you for your response jamesjaya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;

$i += 3;
```

or

```
$i = $i + 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added variable y with a value of 3.
then I change the variable arrlength to variable y.
then increment the variable y by 3.

for($x=$i; $x < $y;$x++)

Thank you for your help guys.